# How to open multiple zipped excel files(.gz file) located in different sub folders at once in dataframe format in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests, ipython

I am new to python so having a problem. I have multiple zipped (.gz)excel files in different sub folders, and I am trying to read all the zipped excel files in dataframe format in python  using the os.listdir function but it's only showing the name. I am facing the problem to read those zipped excel files in DataFrame format, so that I can perform operations on it. Any help would really be appreciated.
I used:

```
path = "/Users/admin/Desktop/Data"

import os
df=os.listdir(path)
from pathlib import Path

for path in Path("path/to/dir").rglob("*.gz"):
    print(path)
```

The above formula is just giving me the name of the files, and not the actual CSV files, I want to perform operation on.
Help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you have at least Python 3.4, you can use the `pathlib` module to apply a recursive glob pattern - in this case, it will iterate over paths (to files, in any sub-directory belonging to the provided path) whose extension / suffix is `.gz`. Each path is an absolute path, and these path objects can easily be cast to strings as well if you need them as strings.

```
from pathlib import Path

for path in Path("path/to/dir").rglob("*.gz"):
    print(path)
```

EDIT - A more concrete example:

```
from pathlib import Path

root_path = "C:/users/admin/desktop/data"

for path in Path(root_path).rglob("*.gz"):
    print("Current path:", path)
    gzip_file = path.open("r")
    # ... do things with gzip_file
```

Comment: Firstly thanks a lot for your time. Secondly, I tried the aforementioned way, but still it's not reading the zipped excel files.

Comment: @Beginner_pyhton Maybe you can post the code you've written so far? Simply edit your original post and paste it there.

Comment: I have edited my question and the code I used, please have a look and suggest a solution. Thanking you.

Comment: @Beginner_pyhton Thanks for editing your post. I've edited my post, too. Take a look. You don't need `os.listdir`.

Comment: I tried the aforementioned way as well, and I am getting gzip_file- TextI0Wrapper (which has nothing in it). I am not sure why is it so. Please suggest a way out.

Comment: Are you passing the `gzip_file` TextIOWrapper object to the `read_csv` function?

Comment: No, I am just giving the root path of my gz file into the code you helped me with. But it is not working unfortunately.